# When using StoryBoards, am I allowed to present view controllers using presentViewController:animated:completion:?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, segue

I would like to know if, when Im using storyboards, can I still present view controllers using the method `presentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL) completion:^(void)completion` ?

Or do I have to use segues?

In my project there is a VC that could be presented by any of the other VCs from the hole app, so if I would use segues, there would be like 20 segues to this same VC.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I use storyboards, but I do have some separate classes with their own .xib files. I present those using that method. If that is what you mean, then yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should still work.  You would use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to create the view controller from its storyboard definition before calling that method.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I was trying with `[myClass alloc] init]` and it wasnt working. And thats why I asked the question in the first place. This solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can basically assign a StoryBoard ID to the UIViewController you want to present by any other UIViewController.

[image: StoryBoard ID]

Then you have to Import the UIViewController subclass in the top of the .h file of the UIViewController that you want it to present it, for Example I've here the BaseViewController and the InfoViewController that I want to present:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    InfoViewController *InfoViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) InfoViewController *InfoViewController;
```

Then in the .m file you have to synthesize it and type implement the code. I'm using here a button to show the InfoViewController with an *IBAction* named *ShowInfoAction*.

```
    @synthesize InfoViewController = _InfoViewController;

    - (IBAction)ShowInfoAction:(id)sender {
        InfoViewController *InfoVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GiveItAnIDHere"];
        [self presentViewController:InfoVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

Comment: btw you'll get a warning if you didn't link the UIViewController by either a segue or assign an ID to it so the StoryBoard can figure that it's part of the *family*. You should never use .xib files if you use StoryBoards. Well you can but it's not recommended.